How to run binary without using `yarn run` (using pnp - no node_modules)
I'm looking for an alternative how to run next binary without calling yarn. Basically I'm trying to avoid calling yarn run next start (because I cannot access yarn in pm2 cluster mode).
I'm using PnP so don't have any node_modules to refer to.
I'm able to run a custom script without yarn using:
NODE_OPTIONS="--require $(pwd)/.pnp.cjs --experimental-loader file://$(pwd)/.pnp.loader.mjs" node ./myscript.js
How can I run a next or any other binary binary in a similar way?

The only way I found is to create a proxy script, e.g.:
NODE_OPTIONS="--require $(pwd)/.pnp.cjs --experimental-loader file://$(pwd)/.pnp.loader.mjs" node ./next-proxy.js
next-proxy.js:
#!/usr/bin/env node

import 'next/dist/bin/next';

